# locaStorage checkbox value in VUEJS - trying to format value being stored

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, supabase

Im saving checkbox value id to localStorage and would like to use this value to retrieve data from supabase that matches this id. Checkbox value is being saved to localStorage but populates likes this.

[image]

Whats the best way to format this so i can match the ID when i fetchdata with supabase and if so, how? template code is below.

```
<div class="flex items-center h-5 absolute z-10 translate-x-3 translate-y-4">
  <input v-model="selected" :value="listings.id" type="checkbox" class="text-[#FF385C] focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 outline-none focus:outline-none h-5 w-5 border border-white rounded-full p-2">
  </div>
```

script code below

```
<script setup>
const selected = ref([]) 
const Local1 = localStorage.getItem('comparable')

watch(selected, newVal => {
localStorage.setItem('comparable', JSON.stringify(newVal)) 
}, {deep: true})
</script>
```

I'm then retrieving the ID in another component with the below. And would like to use the ID's to fetch the matching data from Supabase.

```
const Local1 = localStorage.getItem('comparable')

const fetchData = async () => {
const { data, } = await supabase
.from("airbnb")
.select()
.eq('id', *ID number/s to be passed here* )
Filteredlist1.value = data;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

all good - i retrieved the list properly by using `const Local1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comparable'))` in the other component and retrieved the data using the below function for supabase.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
const { data, } = await supabase
.from("airbnb")
.select()
.in('id', [ Local1 ] )
 Filteredlist1.value = data;
 };
```